# AGGrid Angular: How to invoke a callback function that is derived from a property of an object?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have this editable property defined with a callback in an aggrid column definition

```
{
        colId: 'Bound',
        headerName: 'Bound',
        field: 'bound',
        sortable: true,
        editable: (params: ColumnFunctionCallbackParams) => {
          return !params.useDefaultBound;
        },
        tooltipField: 'Upper Bound',
        filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
          values: ['Low', 'Medium', 'High'],
        },
        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: {
          values: ['Asset', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'],
        },
},
```

And somewhere in the app that editable property is accessed to check its value, which should be true or false. But instead of getting a true or false value, I get the entire body of the callback defined above when I console log it.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/orGuD.png)

Is there a way to invoke this callback to get the value true or false?

```
console.log(colDef.editable);

if (colDef?.editable) {
   menuItems.push(...customMenuItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `colDef?.editable` to call function editable like `colDef?.editable()`

```
if (colDef?.editable()) {
   menuItems.push(...customMenuItems);
}
```

this command `console.log(colDef.editable);` show you value of `colDef` object: this is function (not execute this function), when you execute this function, it return data to you.

Hope this help!